# JavaScript curry

Tags: javascript

I`m a newbie at JavaScript trying to understand this tutorial about currying from Oreilly JavaScript Cookbook.

Could someone be kind enough to explain this program in detail step by step in plain language. Please make sure to explain the "null" argument passed in the second last line of the program. Thank you in advance if you can help.

```
function curry(fn, scope) {
    scope = scope || window;
    var args = [];
    for (var i = 2, len = arguments.length; i < len; ++i) {
        args.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    return function() {
        var args2 = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            args2.push(arguments[i]);
        }
        var argstotal = args.concat(args2);
        return fn.apply(scope, argstotal);
    };
}

function diffPoint(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    return [Math.abs(x2 - x1), Math.abs(y2 - y1)];
}

var diffOrigin = curry(diffPoint, null, 3.0, 4.0);
var newPt = diffOrigin(6.42, 8.0); //produces array with 3
```

Comment: Hey, you found a better JavaScript resource, didn't you! +1

Comment: That's not currying, that's partial application.

Comment: Let's start with the basics - do you understand the purpose of [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) in any other language? Or are you trying to understand it for the first time using this Javascript hack?

Comment: Also he isn't using `args2`, his second loop pushes straight onto `args`...

Comment: _[Partial Function Application is not Currying](http://www.uncarved.com/blog/not_currying.mrk)_ might be a good read, btw.

Comment: @david the tutorial is using arg2. I just made a typo. It`s corrected now. @Greg Hewgill I`m trying to learn it now for the first time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
// define the curry() function
function curry(fn, scope) {

    // set the scope to window (the default global object) if no scope was passed in.
    scope = scope || window;

    // Convert arguments into a plain array, because it is sadly not one.
    // args will have all extra arguments in it, not including the first 2 (fn, scope)
    // The loop skips fn and scope by starting at the index 2 with i = 2
    var args = [];
    for (var i = 2, len = arguments.length; i < len; ++i) {
        args.push(arguments[i]);
    }

    // Create the new function to return
    return function() {

        // Convert any arguments passed to the this function into an array.
        // This time we want them all
        var args2 = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            args.push(arguments[i]);
        }

        // Here we combine any args originally passed to curry, with the args
        // passed directly to this function.
        //   curry(fn, scope, a, b)(c, d)
        // would set argstotal = [a, b, c, d]
        var argstotal = args.concat(args2);

        // execute the original function being curried in the context of "scope"
        // but with our combined array of arguments
        return fn.apply(scope, argstotal);
    };
}

// Create a function to be curried
function diffPoint(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    return [Math.abs(x2 - x1), Math.abs(y2 - y1)];
}

// Create a curried version of the diffPoint() function
//   arg1: the function to curry
//   arg2: the scope (passing a falsy value causes the curry function to use window instead)
//   arg3: first argument of diffPoint() to bake in (x1)
//   arg4: second argument of diffPoint() to bake in (y1)
var diffOrigin = curry(diffPoint, null, 3.0, 4.0);

// Call the curried function
// Since the first 2 args where already filled in with the curry, we supply x2 and y2 only
var newPt = diffOrigin(6.42, 8.0);
```

In this case the `scope` argument isn't used at all.  `scope` sets what the `this` object is.  The function you are currying doesn't use `this` so it has no real effect.  The scope is set when `fn.apply(scope, args)` is called, which both sets the scope to run in and provides arguments to pass in.

Comment: thank you very much. Can you possibly explain how, in diffPoint(), its first argument (3.0) and the second argument (4.0) get "baked in", as you put it. Does that mean they get permanently attached to x1 and x2? How? Much appreciated if you can explain.

Comment: `fn.apply(scope, argstotal);` is the money shot.  apply() will run the function you call it on, in the scope of the first argument, with the arguments in the array of the second argument.  So `fn` is the original function, `scope` is the context (null, then set to `window`), and `argstotal` is the baked arguments plus the arguments yo explicitly pass in.  Now look at how `argstotal` is built.  It takes `args` (the arguments passed along with the curry call), and adds `args2` to it (the arguments passed when calling the curried function).  The result is the original fun, called with all 4 args.

Comment: @AlexWayne I can't edit your answer since it's only a one-char change,  but the `args.push(arguments[i]);` after `var args2 = [];` should be `args2.push(arguments[i]);` instead.

Comment: this function is wrong, it will not work if you call curried function twice: `f = function(a,b) { return a+b; }; g = curry(f, null, 1); g(2); g(3);` both g invications will return 3. You can push to original args array you need to create clone using `slice()`. Or maybe second `args.push(arguments[i]);` should be `args2.push(arguments[i]);`

Answer (score 21):

If you dont mind a suggestion, start with Javascript: The Good Parts. Follow that up with either Javascript Patterns, or Secrets of the Javascript Ninja for more advanced techniques. Cookbooks are more for canned solutions to problems then a learning resource.

Matt Ball did a good job explaining whats going on. If you are a beginner, I wouldn't sweat trying to figure out curry functions anyways. That aside, IMO this curry function is terrible. This is how I would change it

```
// this is doing binding and partial function application, 
// so I thought bind was a more appropriate name
// The goal is that when you execute the returned wrapped version of fn, its this will be scope
function bind(fn, scope) {
  // arguments is an implicit variable in every function that contains a full list
  // of what was passed in. It is important to note that javascript doesn't enforce arity.
  // since arguments is not a true array, we need to make it one.
  // a handy trick for this is to use the slice function from array,
  // since it will take arguments, and return a real array.
  // we are storing it in a variable, because we will need to use it again.
  var slice =  Array.prototype.slice,
      // use slice to get an array of all additional arguments after the first two
      // that have been passed to this function.
      args = slice.call(arguments, 2);

  // we are returning a function mostly as a way to delay the execution.
  // as an aside, that this is possible in a mainstream language is a minor miracle
  // and a big part of why i love javascript.
  return function() {
    // since functions are objects in javascript, they can actually have methods.
    // this is one of the built in ones, that lets you execute a function in a different
    // context, meaning that the this variable inside the 
    // function will actually refer to the first argument we pass in.

    // the second argument we are jamming together the arguments from the first function
    // with the arguments passed in to this wrapper function, and passing it on to fn.
    // this lets us partially apply some arguments to fn when we call bind.
    return fn.apply(scope, args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
  }
}
```

JavaScript, while wonderful, is horribly verbose. Needlessly repeating var while defining your bindings just adds a lot of noise. Also, there is no need to painfully build a real array like that, slice will take arguments and give you a real array back. Especially in this case where we are using it twice, AND we actually want to slice out the first two args anyways. Finally, when you apply and your first arg is null, JavaScript will apply the global object for you. There is no need to do that explicitly.

IMO my 5 line function body kicks the crap out of o'reillys 11 lines, and IMO it is much more readable.

Comment: It's further unnecessary because of [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), but your points are good - O'Reilly's is kind of a WTF. +1

Comment: @Matt Ball: Yeah, at first I was writing this rant about how binding has nothing to do with currying, but then I noticed how there was some currying going on, cause of the arg concatenation from the first function. At the end of the day it looks like it was written by someone that understood FP, but wasn't exactly a JS expert.

Comment: `Function.bind` is not available in all browsers.  It's a pretty recent addition to the language.  But yeah, this is a much better and cleaner implementaiton.

Comment: @Matt Ball: Thanks for the info, I was just using the two terms interchangeably.

Comment: @Matt Briggs, thank you very much for providing this rewrite. It would be greatly appreciated if you could do a step by step breakdown of it in plain language, as I`m still a little lost as to what`s happening in it. I am a newbie trying to get a grasp of programming concepts. I will look into your book suggestions but I also heard that JavaScript the Good Parts is not suitable for newbies.

Comment: @mjmitche: I'll annotate my function if you like, but again, I don't think this is something you should be banging your head against as a beginner. If Javascript: The Good Parts is too advanced, start with http://eloquentjavascript.net/. More newbie oriented, and highly recommended.

Comment: @Matt Briggs. I went through the first 6 chapters of eloquentjavascript, but had to stop because a lot of the programs he built in the later chapters got very complex (at least to me) and he didn`t seem to explain a lot of basic steps the programs took.

Comment: @mjmitche: ok, so maybe start with JavaScript: The Definitive Guide for the real basics, eloquent javascript and the good parts for a handle on more advanced features, and then js patterns or secrets of the js ninja for advanced techniques using the advanced features. and for the record, currying is one of those advanced techniques using advanced features. I do js job interviews at work, 99% of so called front end experts would not be able to explain whats going on in that function.

Comment: @Matt Briggs thanks for all your help Matt, and thanks for pointing out that most "experts" wouldn`t understand it. I`ve been wondering, from a practical standpoint if I continue with JavaScript (which I like so far) and someday try to get a job with it, how much advanced knowledge is expected and desired in someone to be useful on the job. When a company is looking for someone who knows JavaScript do they want someone who can make them rollovers? or more substantial features?

Comment: @mjmitche: 99% of the time they want someone who can do rollovers. Expertise in js usually means a good knowledge of jquery to most companies, and that is good enough to do about 80-90% of what you need to do for most projects. Personally, I think someone who specializes in something should actually have more then a passing familiarity with the language, but in the grand scheme of programmers doing web development, that seems to be a minority opinion. The good news is that means if you can describe how to write a curry function in an interview, you are way passed most people that will walk in.

Comment: @Matt_Briggs-- when you `return` `this.apply(scope,args.concat(slice.apply(arguments)))` how can you apply your `slice` method to `args` since the latter has not been made into a proper array yet?

Answer (score 3):

The function `curry` allows you to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) a function `f` (the first parameter to `curry`) to a scope `c` (the second parameter), with optional additional arguments (the rest of the parameters).

That means that this function call:

```
curry(func, scope);
```

*returns* a function `newFunc` whose invocation:

```
var newFunc = curry(func, scope); // get the new function
newFunc(); // now invoke it
```

is equivalent to this:

```
scope.func();
```

The net effect of all this is for the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/this) keyword to refer to `scope`* inside of `func`.

---

#### Concrete example time

Let's say that `scope` is a simple JS object with one property:

```
var scope = {name: 'Inigo Montoya'};
```

and that `f` is a function which wants to use some value inside of `scope`:

```
function f() {
    return 'My name is ' + scope.name;
}
```

and call it, like this:

```
f(); // returns 'My name is Inigo Montoya'
```

Well, that's one way to do it. It works.

Another way to do it would be using the `curry` function. Instead of `f` having to know to reference the `scope` object, `scope` is now the function's invocation context. Now the function can use the `this` keyword!

```
function f_new() {
    return 'My name is ' + this.myName; // see the difference?
}

var sayIt = curry(f, scope);
```

Now `sayIt` is a function that doesn't care *what* `scope` is called. It's like `sayIt` is defined on the `scope` object, like this:

```
var scope = { name: 'Inigo Montoya',
              sayIt: f_new }
```

...except that's not *actually* how `scope` is defined. `sayIt` just works that way. Now, we can call `sayIt`, like this:

```
sayIt(); // returns 'My name is Inigo Montoya'
```

---

#### Still with me?

*Phew*. The point of all this is to say that, in your example, `null` is being provided as the scope for `diffOrigin` to run it, because **it doesn't care about what's in the scope**. The line (in `curry`) `scope = scope || window;` means that, if `scope` is a falsy value (which `null` is) then the new function (`diffOrigin` in this case) will execute in global scope: `this` will refer to `window`.

---

#### Does that make sense to you?

---

<sup>*which is called the "invocation context"</sup>

Comment: I think the scope binding is probably secondary to the main goal of the function, which is allowing you to partially apply the function's arguments.

Comment: @david: yes, this `curry` function does things other than [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) in the traditional sense. I'm just trying to break it down into manageable bites.

Comment: It doesn't do currying at all. It does partial application. And I still think you should be focusing on that rather than the scope. Specifying the scope is just an added extra.

Answer (score 1):

Squeegy posted a good breakdown, but I figured I'd add mine too.

```
//Things to note, 'arguments' is a special variable in javascript that holds 
//an array like object full of all the things passed into a function.
//You can test this out with a function like this:
//var alertArgs = function(){alert(arguments);};

function curry(fn, scope) {
    //Either use the passed in 'scope' object, or the window object as your scope
    scope = scope || window;
    //Create a new array for storing the arguments passed into this function
    var args = [];
    //Loop through the extra arguments (we start at '2' because the first two
    //arguments were stored in `fn` and `scope` respectively.
    //We store these in the temporary 'args' array.
    //(in the example, args will end up looking like: [3.0, 4.0])
    for (var i = 2, len = arguments.length; i < len; ++i) {
        args.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    //We return the 'curried' function
    return function() {
        //This array is not used. I assume it is an error.
        var args2 = [];
        //We now have a new set of arguments, passed in to the curried function
        //We loop through these new arguments, (in the example, 6.42 and 8.0)
        //and add them to the arguments we have already saved. In the end, we have
        //the args array looking like: [3.0, 4.0, 6.42, 8.0]
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            args.push(arguments[i]);
        }
        //This line isn't needed, because args2 is always blank.
        var argstotal = args.concat(args2);

        //Finally we call the function, passing in the full array of arguments
        return fn.apply(scope, argstotal);
    };
}

//This function takes 4 arguments
function diffPoint(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    return [Math.abs(x2 - x1), Math.abs(y2 - y1)];
}

//We partially apply the first 2 arguments, so x1 is always 3.0, 
//and y1 is always 4.0
var diffOrigin = curry(diffPoint, null, 3.0, 4.0);

//We can now call 'diffPoint' indirectly, without having to specify 
//3.0, 4.0 as the first 2 arguments.
var newPt = diffOrigin(6.42, 8.0); //produces array with 3
```

Comment: thank you. can you please explain in simple language the purpose and practical effect of using, for example, window object as scope. What if something else were passed in. What does all this mean?

Comment: To be perfectly honest `scope` is a terrible name, all that that section is doing is deciding what the `this` keyword resolves to when you finally call the function. It doesn't change the actual scope of the function.

Answer (score 1):

This version allows for partial application which returns a new curried function.

```
function curry(fn) {
  const args = [];
  let i = 0;
  const n = arguments.length;

  while (++i < n) {
    args.push(arguments[i]);
  }

  // Functions have a 'length' property which tells us their 'arity'
  // 'arity' means the number of arguments a function can take.
  // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity
  //
  // Here we count the number of arguments that we have and compare
  // it to the number of arguments the function can take.
  // If the function takes an equal or more amount, we have all our
  // arguments and execute the function.
  //
  return args.length >= fn.length
    // '.apply' will convert an array to a list of arguments.
    // 'null' is the context, which is essentially 'this'
    ? fn.apply(null, args) 
    : function () {
      let i = -1;
      const n = arguments.length;
      const args2 = [];

      while (++i < n) {
        args2.push(arguments[i]);
      }

      // We return a curried function which will get checked
      // for arity. Using recursion, we can keep creating newly
      // partially applied functions which can help us to 'compose'
      // new functions.
      // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_%28computer_science%29
      return curry.apply(null, [fn].concat(args.concat(args2)));
    };
}
```