# Javascript curry: context in returned function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, closures

In a curry function like this :

```
var curry = function() {
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice,
        args = slice.call(arguments),
        fn = args.shift();

    return function(){
        return fn.apply(null, args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
    };
};
```

is there any difference between `this` or `null` in `fn.apply` ? I don't see a case where it could make a difference.

---

EDIT :

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14378449/1909827) I think it's pretty clear now, here is a little example I made to undersand it :

```
function msg() {
    console.log(this.name);
}

var foo = { name: "foo"};

var msg_this = curry_this(msg);
var msg_null = curry_null(msg);

msg_this();         //msg.call(null) -> undefined
msg_null();         //msg.call(null) -> undefined
msg_this.call(foo); //msg.call(foo) -> foo
msg_null.call(foo); //msg.call(null) -> undefined
```

with `curry_this` returning `fn.apply(this,...` and `curry_null` returning `fn.apply(null...`

Comment: Yes, it determines what will `this` inside of the function stand for. You could put there any arbitrary object too.

Comment: Learn more about `this`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

Comment: I understand the concept of `this` but I didn't see how it could matters in this function

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176313/javascript-curry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176313/javascript-curry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `null` to apply makes the context the global one (`window` in a browser).

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) :

> if the method is a function in non-strict mode code, null and
>   undefined will be replaced with the global object, and primitive
>   values will be boxed.

How this will impact the result depends on the `fn` function (the first argument to `curry`) and on how you call it.

See this code :

```
var a = {curried: curry(function(){console.log(this)})};
a.curried();
```

If you pass `null` to apply, it logs `window` instead of the object `a`.