# How to implement function with multiple invocations

Tags: javascript, function, method-invocation

How do I implement a adder function in javascript which can be invoked like

```
adder(1,2)(5,6,2)(4,9,10,11)(6,7).....()
```

The function should accept any number of arguments and add them all together. The function can be invoked in following ways.

```
adder(2,3,5) // prints 10
adder(2,3)(5) // prints 10
adder(2)(3)(5) //prints 10
```

What is best possible way to implement this function using closures?

Comment: Why do you want to implement this syntax?

Comment: Read about currying - http://www.crockford.com/javascript/www_svendtofte_com/code/curried_javascript/index.html, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176313/javascript-curry

Comment: you could use the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object for variable parameters of the function.

Comment: sorry, this was marked as a duplicate... there is simple solution to this; the linked answer performs convoluted and unnecessary steps. This question got closed before I could post my answer, but the gist was: use the `arguments` object to loop thru each passed number, summing those to a value like `sum`. At the end of the function, return `adder.bind( null, sum )`. Calling this returned function will add each number you pass it with the previous sum.

Answer (score 0):

```
function add(...values){
 this.value=(this.value||0)+values.reduce((a,b)=>a+b),0);
 return add.bind(this);
}
```

You need a way to pass the value out of your function, i put the value into the context:

```
add(1,2,3)(4,5);
alert(value);
```